# Optimize WPF for large STL files

Tags: c#, wpf, optimization

I am fairly new to WPF and I am wondering:
Is there a way to optimize the performance of WPF(C#) when working with large meshes?
I have a STL file to read (~160000 triangles) and I use some instructions from [here](http://www.kindohm.com/technical/WPF3DTutorial.htm). My program workflow is:

1. Load STL file to byte array
2. Read all points and normals data from byte array to a custom class with Point3D and Vector3D variables
3. Use a method similar to "private Model3DGroup CreateTriangleModel()"
4. Load the resulting Model3DGroup of triangles in a ModelVisual3D model
5. this.mainViewport.Children.Add(model);

Is there a more direct way to load points/normals/triangles/surfaces to the viewport to avoid some of the steps?
From what i see now the same data is reused in different structures. One structure passing the same data to the next.

*The biggest overhead is in step 3. And my concern is that when I load 1000 triangles it takes 458ms, but for 2000 it takes 1280ms, for 4000 - 4076ms and so on geometrically progressing. All the other steps execute in a flash.

**I thought rendering would be the biggest timespender, but as it seems it is loading the data from points to meshes to models to groups.

Basically I have a stlModel which holds an array of StlTriangles(a class containing 3 vertice points3D and 1 normal vector3D):

```
Model3DGroup model3D = new Model3DGroup();
                Material objectMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Coral));
                GeometryModel3D triangle;
                MeshGeometry3D mesh;
                ModelVisual3D solidModel3D = new ModelVisual3D();

                stlModel.loadTriangles();

                for (int i = 0; i < stlModel.Triangles.Length; i++)
                {
                    mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
                    mesh.Positions.Add(stlModel.Triangles[i].Vertex1);
                    mesh.Positions.Add(stlModel.Triangles[i].Vertex2);
                    mesh.Positions.Add(stlModel.Triangles[i].Vertex3);
                    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
                    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                    mesh.Normals.Add(stlModel.Triangles[i].Normal);
                    mesh.Normals.Add(stlModel.Triangles[i].Normal);
                    mesh.Normals.Add(stlModel.Triangles[i].Normal);

                    triangle = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, objectMaterial);

                    model3D.Children.Add(triangle);
                }

                solidModel3D.Content = model3D;

                this.mainViewport.Children.Add(solidModel3D);
```

Comment: Do you have the source for CreateTriangleModel?

Comment: @Andy: it's near the bottom of the page in the [tutorial link](http://www.kindohm.com/technical/WPF3DTutorial.htm).

Comment: There is a list of advices from MSDN regarding `MeshGeometry3D` performance. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613553.aspx Of those, you should try array size preallocation first.

Comment: Very nice use for GeometryModel3D, but the link is broken!

Comment: Expanding the tip from @rwong, another relevant one from the same link is: "When a mesh is defined as abutting triangles with shared vertices and those vertices have the same position, normal, and texture coordinates, define each shared vertex only once and then define your triangles by index with TriangleIndices." It seems like STL will most often have LOTS of repeated indices/edges.